# Weird unwanted phrases in my table of content! How to get rid of this?

Tags: table-of-contents

Here is a screenshot of my table of content (amsart documentclass) :
[image: TOC]

I do not want these Section *.2, Section *.3, Section *.4 in between the actual lines. How do I get rid of these inexplicable phrases? Thank you.

---

Apparently the problem is occurring due to the use of my self-defined command `\addsubsection*` instead of `\subsection*` (because I do not want the subsections to be shown in the table of contents).

---

A minimal code:

```
 \pdfoutput=1
 \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,reqno]{amsart}
 \usepackage{amssymb}

 \usepackage{bm}
 \numberwithin{equation}{section}

 \usepackage{mathabx}
 \usepackage{mathrsfs}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \usepackage{color}



 \theoremstyle{plain}

 \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
 \newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
 \newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
 \newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
 \newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
 \newtheorem{principle}[theorem]{Principle}
 \newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}

 \theoremstyle{definition}

 \newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
 \newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
 \newtheorem{remarks}[theorem]{Remarks}
 \newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
 \newtheorem{examples}[theorem]{Examples}

 \newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}
 \newcommand\Z{\mathbb{Z}}
 \newcommand\N{\mathbb{N}}
 \newcommand\Q{\mathbb{Q}}
 \newcommand\eps{\varepsilon}
 \newcommand\normsymb{\ell}  % was \|\,\|
 \newcommand\norm[1]{\ell({#1})}   % was \|{#1}\|
 \newcommand\normn[1]{\ell_n({#1})}   % was \|{#1}\|
 \newcommand\free[1]{\mathbf{F}_{#1}}

 %\vast \Vast - Bigger than \Bigg
 \makeatletter
 \newcommand{\vast}{\bBigg@{4}}
 \newcommand{\Vast}{\bBigg@{5}}
 \makeatother

 %\addsubsection - not shown in toc
 \makeatletter
 \ifcsname phantomsection\endcsname
  \newcommand*{\qrr@gobblenexttocentry}[5]{}
 \else
  \newcommand*{\qrr@gobblenexttocentry}[4]{}
 \fi
 \newcommand*{\addsubsection}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\qrr@gobblenexttocentry}%
  \subsection}
 \makeatother

 \usepackage[breaklinks=true,hidelinks]{hyperref}


 \begin{document}

 \title{TITLE}

 \maketitle
 %\today

 \tableofcontents %\need to fix it

 \section{Introduction}
 \label{section-introduction}

 bla bla bla...

 \vspace{0.2cm}
 \addsubsection*{blablabla}
 We consider this and that, that and that..

 \vspace{0.2cm}
 \section{New section}

 \vspace{0.2cm}
 \addsubsection*{here we are}

 \addsubsection*{also here}

 \vspace{0.2cm}
 \section{The main theorem}

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current definition of `\addsubsection` inserts `\qrr@gobblenexttocentry` into the ToC in an attempt to gobble a subsequent entry of `\contentsline`. This may seem appropriate, but two `\addsubsection`s immediately following one another causes a problem, since the gobbling becomes out-of-sync. Moreover, if you wish to define `\qrr@gobblenexttocentry` to be conditional on the existence of `\phantomsection` (when [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) is loaded), it's obvious that which branch will be chosen since you're loading `hyperref` *after* this.

There's a far better way of doing what you're after: Use `\subsection` (starred or not) as-is and add to your preamble

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
```

The above will only print ToC entries up to `\section`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\let\addsubsection\subsection
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents %\need to fix it

\section{Introduction}

\addsubsection*{blablabla}

\section{New section}

\addsubsection*{here we are}

\addsubsection*{also here}

\section{The main theorem}

\end{document}
```

Technically this allows you to get rid of `\addsubsection` altogether. I've left it in the above code, making it similar to `\subsection`.

Comment: Excellent. That's what I wanted. Thank you sir.

Comment: And thanks for the detailed clarification for why the previous definition did not work. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found a solution. It's a bit of cheating really but produces the same result.

I replaced

```
\addsubsection*{subsection-name}
```

with

```
\noindent\textbf{subsection-name.}
```

I guess it's a situation when we were looking for an flamethrower where a simple lighter would have worked. However, it is still an interesting problem to find code for self-defined subsection that does not show up in the toc.

Comment: why not simple `\subsection*{subsection title}`? read @Werner  answer carefully again.

Comment: @Zarko the name of the subsection along with the page number still shows in the table of contents (just without the subsection number).

Comment: apparently you not understand @Werner. with`\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}` in toc will appear only sections. remove your `\addsubsection` definition. it is superfluous.

Comment: You're right! So all I needed is
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
Thank you so much!

Comment: and use standard `subsection{...}` (if you like to be numbered) or `\subsection*{...}` (for unnumbered) :-)